# Control '0' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: asp.net

there is dynamic table that i created(on server-side), the cols is(irem,price, pic and textxbox),
when i try to add the textbox i getting the messege **Control '0' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server**
.

here is the code (case 4 is where i create the textbox ):

```
  protected void createTable()
{
    int numberOfItems = mylist.Count;



    // Create a new HtmlTable object.
    HtmlTable table1 = new HtmlTable();

    // Set the table's formatting-related properties.
    table1.Border = 1;
    table1.CellPadding = 1;
    table1.CellSpacing = 1;
    table1.BorderColor = "red";

    // Start adding content to the table.
    HtmlTableRow row;
    HtmlTableCell cell;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        // Create a new row and set its background color.
        row = new HtmlTableRow();
        row.BgColor = "lightyellow";
        row.Height = Convert.ToString(100);


        name = mylist[i].Name;
        price = mylist[i].Price;
        image = mylist[i].ImagePath;




        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            // Create a cell and set its text.
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();




            switch (j)
            {
                case 1:
                    cell.InnerHtml = name;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell.InnerHtml = Convert.ToString(price);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell.InnerHtml = image;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
                    txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                    txt.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    cell.Controls.Add(txt);
                    break;
                default:

                    break;


            }

            // Add the cell to the current row.

            row.Cells.Add(cell);
        }

        // Add the row to the table.
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // Add the table to the page.
    this.Controls.Add(table1);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your question, as the error says, all controls that have the `runat=server` must be placed inside a form that has the `runat=server` tag too.
In your case, you're adding the table (which has a server-side `Textbox`) as a ***root element*** in your page, using this line:

```
this.Controls.Add(table1);
```

**Instead,** you should add it as an element *inside* the `<form></form>` tag.
This can easily be done by either adding an id attribute to your main form (e.g. `<form runat="server" id="myForm">` in your aspx page and then, instead of `this.Controls.Add()` use:

```
myForm.Controls.Add(table1);
```

Or, just put an empty `div` with `runat=server` somewhere in your aspx page
(e.g. `<div id=myDiv runat=server />`) and add the table to that div:

```
myDiv.Controls.Add(table1);
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but I'm trying to programatically render an ASCX file which contains a server side control in a web service. How would I programatically add a DIV to my page, so I can add the server side control to that?

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707826/how-can-i-programtically-build-a-system-web-ui-page-with-a-form-and-a-usercontro