# How can I programmatically build a System.Web.UI.Page with a Form and a UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asmx, ascx

I have this code:

```
public static string RenderView(string path)
{
    Page pageHolder = new Page();
    UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);

    pageHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Which is run from:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string GetReportsHTML()
    {
        string output = "";

        output = ViewManager.RenderView("ReportsControl.ascx");

        return output;
    }
```

This is to test rendering ASCX files and spitting them out of a SOAP/REST service.

Problem is, some controls (runat=server ones) fail if they are not encapsulated in a  tag with runat=server.

The solution to that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777442/control-0-of-type-textbox-must-be-placed-inside-a-form-tag-with-runat-server/13777536#comment20569725_13777536), but the solution assumes being inside an ASPX file where I can just edit the markup.

How would I programmatically build a Page, add a Form, set runat=server so that I can follow that solution and add my control to the Form Control?

Comment: You could build a static page with a PlaceHolder control, and then load your UserControl into that.

Comment: Wouldn't the references to any objects on the page that run server-side have to be compiled for referencing, as per the requirement for a `*.aspx.designer.cs`/`vb` file?

Comment: Um, don't know, but jbl's answer works. I just didn't know the name of the server side wrapper around the HTML <FORM> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
public static string RenderView(string path)
{
    Page pageHolder = new Page();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm formHolder = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
    pageHolder.Controls.Add(formHolder );

    UserControl viewControl = (UserControl)pageHolder.LoadControl(path);

    formHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);

    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Hope this will help