# Issues rendering UserControl using Server.Execute()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

When Server.Execute() myusercontrol that contain controls of asp(not html) i  received the following message

[image]

UserControl:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyWebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="ImageHandlerClient.WebUserControl1" %>
```

Stack Trace:

```
 at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
```

Comment: What is your question? Did you check the exception message (by clicking "View Detail..." under "Actions" in the popup)?

Comment: Error executing child request means there is something wrong INSIDE the ascx, ...

Comment: When execute ascx file that all contents is HTML work fine but when add control of asp like button not work

Comment: Use @Igor approach to get the inner exception, and add the contents of the stack trace to your post.  We can't help with this issue until we find out what the inner exception is.

Comment: I edit question and add stack trace

Comment: @ZSH - not enough. There is actual message that says what the error is, which you still are withholding.

Comment: In innerExceptin ({"Control 'ctl00_Button1' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server."}) when i put button ic <form runat="server">   received error:"A page can have only one server-side Form tag"

Comment: I guess you need to dynamically inject a form control : see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14710535/1236044

Comment: Thank you,it works but in one of controllers i use <obout:Tree > when execute received error:"{"This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add <head runat=\"server\" />."}"

Answer (score 0):

About the Head runat="server", you may try this :

```
public static string RenderView(string controlName)
{
    var pageHolder = new System.Web.UI.Page();
    var headHolder = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead();

    pageHolder.Controls.Add(headHolder);
    var formHolder = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
    pageHolder.Controls.Add(formHolder);

    // dynamically adding a script manager
    var sm = new System.Web.UI.ScriptManager();
    formHolder.Controls.Add(sm);


    var viewControl = pageHolder.LoadControl(controlName);

    formHolder.Controls.Add(viewControl);

    var output = new StringWriter();
    HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(pageHolder, output, false);

    return output.ToString();
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I receive this error:"A ScriptManager is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components."

Comment: @ZSH the same holds : dynamically adding a scriptmanager (updated my answer) But, if your goal is to extract the control's issued html code, I'm afraid it won't be working on the client side.